# jQueryMobile - Why is a new dynamically generated page not updated to the last version?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-mobile

I'm generating pages dynamically in jQueryMobile, but I can't understand why the new generated page is not updated to the last version.

This is the use case:

Page A contains a list of 'a' elements. When I click one, the app redirects to a new page that is generated dynamically. Then I go back to page A. I click another 'a' element, but from now on, the app will always redirect to the first page that was dynamically generated.

Please look at this fiddle:

http://fiddle.jshell.net/cqUrD/

This is my code:

HTML

```
<div data-role="page" id="home">
    <div data-role="header" data-position="fixed">
         <h1>static page</h1>

    </div>
    <div data-role="content"> <a href="#" data-role="button" id="createfirst">Create new page</a>
        <div data-role="content"> <a href="#" data-role="button" id="createanother">Create another new page</a>

    </div>
    <div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed">
         <h1>footer</h1>

    </div>
</div>
```

jQueryMobile:

```
$(document).on('click','a',function() {
  nameId = $(this).attr('id');
    page = '<div data-role="page" id="page" data-theme="e"><div data-  role="header"><a data-role="button" href="#" data-rel="back" data-icon="back" data-iconpos="notext">back</a><h1>Dynamic page</h1></div><div data-role="content"> Last id was: '+nameId+'</div><div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed"><h1>footer</h1></div></div>';
    //alert(nameId); this prints the right value
  $.mobile.activePage.after(page);
    $.mobile.changePage('#page', {
        transition: 'flip'
    });
});
```

How can I solve this problem? I need to always show the updated version of the new page.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: My guess is its cached and since its the same href with the same id its not being recreated. I have solved problems such as this by making  the url always unique by using a timestamp.  Append time() onto the url.  You'll find examples on google.

Comment: thanks Jake. Based on your suggestion I edited the code this way and it worked: http://fiddle.jshell.net/CFJtZ/1/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/Gajotres/Xfh8p/

Before new page is created previous one must be removed. In this case a **`DOM`** was filled with new pages but first one was still there and because they all had same name that first one had a priority.

Also when binding a click event don't bind it to a tag only, this was also a problem. Each time return button was pressed another page was created in **`DOM`**.

All in all this will work:

```
$(document).on('pageinit', '#home', function(){ 
    $(document).on('click','#createfirst, #createanother',function() {
        nameId = $(this).attr('id');
        alert(nameId);
        page = '<div data-role="page" id="page" data-theme="e"><div data-  role="header"><a data-role="button" href="#" data-rel="back" data-icon="back" data-iconpos="notext">back</a><h1>Dynamic page</h1></div><div data-role="content">'+nameId+'</div><div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed"><h1>footer</h1></div></div>';
        $.mobile.activePage.after(page);
        $.mobile.changePage('#page', {
            transition: 'flip'
        });
    });
});

$(document).on('pagehide', '#page', function(){ 
    $(this).remove();
});
```

In this case **`pagehide`** event has been bound to dynamically created page. Because it is bound to the document object it will still be there when page is removed. It tells **`jQuery Mobile`** to remove page #page during the transition from it.

As you can see I have used jQuery Mobile page events to trigger a page removal. If you want to find more about this topic take a look at my other **[ARTICLE](http://www.gajotres.net/document-onpageinit-vs-document-ready/)** (my personal blog) or find it **[HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14469041/1848600)**.

Answer (score 1):

When you are clicking the button second time, the page with same ID is already in DOM so I think jQuery is unable to create a second one with the same ID (maybe caching). I changed the code a bit. You need to remove the `#page` if it already exists.

```
if ($('body').find('#page').length != 0) $("#page").remove();
```

Link: http://fiddle.jshell.net/cqUrD/1/